# anaconda env couldn't import any of the packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

**pip list inside conda env:**
pip list
matplotlib (1.4.0)
nose (1.3.7)
numpy (1.9.1)
pandas (0.15.2)
pip (8.1.2)
pyparsing (2.0.1)
python-dateutil (2.4.1)
pytz (2016.4)
scikit-learn (0.15.2)
scipy (0.14.0)
setuptools (21.2.1)
six (1.10.0)
wheel (0.29.0)

**which python:**

/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/pythonenvname/bin/python

(pythonenvname)pc-xx-xx:oo xxx$ **which pip**

/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/pythonenvname/bin/pip

python
Python 3.4.4 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jan  9 2016, 17:30:09)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import pandas as pd **error:**
> > >       **sh: sysctl: command not found**

Comment: I'd recommend just installing pandas with conda.  Try doing `conda install pandas`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply in the first place. This is happening on for the first time I import. >>> import pandas as pd
sh: sysctl: command not found
>>> import pandas as pd. It imported when I reissue the command one more time. @Paul

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out the answer. It is all about the PATH variable. It was pointing to os python rather than anaconda python. Thanks all for your time.